# jquery function on dropdown select

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I need to run a jquery function if a certain dropdown option is selected.

```
<select name=dropdown size=1>
    <option value=1>option 1</option>
    <option value=2>option 2</option>
</select>
```

I have the commands in the function ready, Im just not sure on how to make it so if option 2 is currently active in the dropdown, then run the function.

(dropdown doesnt have a submit button, i want it ran when the user highlights the option)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try this **demo** http://jsfiddle.net/JGp9e/

This will help, have a nice one!

**code**

```
$('select[name="dropdown"]').change(function(){

    if ($(this).val() == "2"){
        alert("call the do something function on option 2");
     }        
});​
```

**HTML**

```
<select name="dropdown" size=1>
    <option value="1">option 1</option>
    <option value="2">option 2</option>
</select>​
```

Comment: what if you want it triggered even if the same thing was selected ?

Answer (score 7):

use

```
$("#idofselectbox").change(function(){
// your code here
});
```

hope this helps....

Answer (score 7):

Try this one, [Demo on JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/22dDE/)

```
$('select[name="dropdown"]').change(function() {
    alert($(this).val());

});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select[name='dropdown']").change(function() {
     alert($(this).val());
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `change` function

```
$('select[name=dropdown]').change(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("select[name='dropdown']").change(function() {
         if($(this).val()==2){
             //do what u want here
           }//u can check your desired value here
     });
   });
```

I think you want this.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way can be as following:

```
<select name="select" id="select" onChange="window.location = this.value">
  <option value="/en">English</option>
  <option value="/ps">Pashto</option>
</select>
```