# jquery - problems with function on Dropdown Select

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I've got a problem with a Wordpress plugin that creates many dynamic selection boxes "dropdown boxes" on a single page of my website. Its an ecommerce website. The plugin is 'Composite Products'.

Unfortunately this plugin gives each dropdown the same ID and Class. Ouch.

I'm happily using a modified version of code, from here- 
[jquery function on dropdown select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10481503/jquery-function-on-dropdown-select)

I use this use the 'var' (which is unique) of a selected item, the selection is used to re-define CSS elsewhere on the page.

**My Problem –** on a separate drop-down (class = .component_options_select ) I'm trying to select further selections by text, or html. Both fail. I can't use var, as the contents of this drop-down are vast and dynamic. Is there a better search function for jquery?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('select[class="component_options_select"]').change(function(){

        if ($(this).val() == "6785")
            $(".element-to-change").css({"width":"530px"})
            .add(".blaeu-prints-builder-inner").css({"background-image":"url('/storefront-blaeu/gfx/12x16.jpg')"},100);

        if ($(this).val() == "6786")
            $(".element-to-change").css({"width":"550px"})
            .add(".blaeu-prints-builder-inner").css({"background-image":"url('/storefront-blaeu/gfx/18x24.jpg')"},100);

        if ($(this).val() == "6787")
            $(".element-to-change").css({"width":"600px"})
            .add(".blaeu-prints-builder-inner").css({"background-image":"url('/storefront-blaeu/gfx/27x39.jpg')"},100);

    });
});
```

So that much works, but here's the next line of code which has no effect.

```
        if ($(this).text() == "This Selection")
      $(".another-element-i-want-to-edit").css('display','block');
```

I've tried using .html and .text, also option-contains text... Neither work. I'm not very talented with JQuery!

Any help most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

If

```
if ($(this).text() == "This Selection"){
    $(".another-element-i-want-to-edit").css('display','block');
}
```

is in the same `change` function of the select, it will not work as you need to check the value not the text. Meaning change

```
if ($(this).text() == "This Selection")
```

to

```
if ($(this).val() == "This Selection")
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This doesn't work in my case. I'm not exactly sure what's happening. But in plain english-

it seems the Dropdown box'es ID / Class is used on two items on the same page, they're shown via an accordion in a 'product builder' situation.

so the first instance I use ($(this).val() to do something (change CSS) on a certain selection, x3

... for the second drop-down, which as mentioned shares the same ID / Class... I want to use .text (or as you mention .val). But this doesn't seem to work. Messy.

Comment: Understood. Could you post a snippet of the html and js working together (or not working as it should in your case)? So I can give an exact solution based on your exact code?

Comment: I thank you for your help, but I think there is another JQuery function going on- via the plugin, its automatically changing the content of the drop down (on selection). I tried your code in a situation without the plugin, and it works. 

So I'm going to write another solution. 

I'm sorry for not helping to get to the bottom of this. But its a Premium Wordpress plugin, I don't want to start pasting the developer's code on SO. Sorry.

Comment: Well, I didn't ask you to paste the whole plugin buddy. Just the relevant code to your problem. If you don't want to do that and rather take care of it yourself, then be my guest. No harm no foul.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I realised I could edit the plugin to create a list of 'checkboxes' rather than a second 'drop down' list, sharing the ID / Class of the first. So I've found a solution. Thanks very much for your time. All the best.